# Parsing div embedded in a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

I am trying to parse the data since I made the cell content editable. Here is my Jquery

```js
$('#presend_btn').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("presend_btn preparations");

  $('#reporting-agent-data').each(function() {
    var tmpdiv = $(this).find('.agent-data');

    var agent_id = $(tmpdiv).attr('agent-id');
    console.log("agent_id: " + agent_id);


    $(tmpdiv).each(function() {
      var rname = $(tmpdiv).find('.r-name').val();
      console.log("rname: " + rname);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reporting-agent-data">
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="1">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="2">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="3">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not getting the wanted result from the Jquery code. The expected result was that parsing parent div with id 'reporting-agent-data', getting child div with class 'agent-data' attribute of 'agent-id' and then getting child div with class 'r-name' value. Instead I get only first child agent-id value and 3 instances of 'r-name' come empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: val() only returns the value of HTML input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `$(tmpdiv).each()` use `$(this)` instead of `$(tmpdiv)`. Also move your code `var agent_id = $(tmpdiv).attr('agent-id');` and use `$(this)` here also.

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()` at `$(this).find('.r-name').text();`. `.val()` will not apply for `div`.

Check it below.

```js
$('#presend_btn').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("presend_btn preparations");

  $('#reporting-agent-data').each(function() {
    var tmpdiv = $(this).find('.agent-data');

    $(tmpdiv).each(function() {
      var agent_id = $(this).attr('agent-id');
      console.log("agent_id: " + agent_id);
      var rname = $(this).find('.r-name').text();
      console.log("rname: " + rname);
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.reported-cell {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.reported-cell-textarea {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='presend_btn' value='presend_btn' />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reporting-agent-data">
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="1">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="2">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="3">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) only return when there is a value on an `input` element or data attr.

In your case there is `NONE` so what you apparently need is the [.text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) of your `r-name`

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$('#presend_btn').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("presend_btn preparations");

  $('#reporting-agent-data').each(function() {
    var tmpdiv = $(this).find('.agent-data');

    
    $(tmpdiv).each(function() {
      //Agent IDs
      var agent_id = $(this).attr('agent-id');
      console.log("agent_id: " + agent_id);
       //R Names
      var rname = $(this).find('.r-name').text() //THis needs a fix
      console.log("rname: " + rname);
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reporting-agent-data">
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="1">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'>1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="2">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'>2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center agent-data equal" agent-uuid="0" agent-id="3">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-name" contenteditable='true'>3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 reported-cell r-relation" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 reported-cell r-phone" contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 reported-cell-textarea r-details" contenteditable='true'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="presend_btn">
 Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: It should be `$(this).attr` and `$(this).find` instead of `$(tmpdiv)`.

Comment: @Karan Would that make the results different or any performance issue ?

Comment: Yes, it will return different result then expected. OP wants to select `text` inside `.r-name` for current `div.agent-data`. `$(this).find('.r-name')` will give you `.r-name` inside current div from `.each`. While `$(tmpdiv).find('.r-name')` will return `.r-name` from all three `div.agent-data`.

Comment: Simply just use `console.log($(this).attr('agent-id'))` and `console.log($(this).find('.r-name').text())` with your existing ones and you will understood the difference.

Comment: @Karan i agree with you. I forgot to add `$(this)` this when i moved the code here from JS fiddle. Appreciate your comment :)